# No assemblyinfo.cs file created for an iOS sample application in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I understand that to enable XAML compilation I am supposed to add a line to the assemblyinfo.cs

But where is it for the iOS project in forms?

I see this file created in the properties folder for Android but not for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an assemblyinfo.cs for iOS projects, it only exists in the Properties folder of the Android project.

Similar functionality for iOS exists in the Entitlements and Info.plist files, but the syntax is different.

If you need to add something to the assemblyinfo.cs then it's for the Android side only, there *might* be an equivalent for iOS, certainly for a new Xamarin Forms app there shouldn't be anything extra you need to add

Comment: Thanks Andy, should I have one in the main project (not the iOS or Android)?  I have some XAML files there and I noticed when I added an assemblyinfo.cs and [assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] to that file that it then checked the XAML on build.

Comment: You need the Xamlcompilationoptions lines yes, but not an assemblyinfo.cs

Comment: Thanks Andy,  accepted your answer.  More questions to come over the next few days :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly correct, you still need something like AssemblyInfo.cs if you are going to force WebView to use the WKWebView instead of the default UIWebView and you need this to be declared outside any namespace, I don't think you can force this using the Entitlements but I may be wrong,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#performance